# Filtering a list with recurrences

Tags: list-view, filter

I have an employee out list that I am working with that has five different views.  The views range from leave, modified workday, to alternate work schedule.  My alternate work schedule view has a recurrence of every week on the same day the employee works from home.

I need to filter the view through the list view web part to only show the "event" on the employee's alternate work schedule day (say every Tuesday).

Does anyone have a solution for something like this.?

[image]

Comment: To put it simply, is your requirement to have a view for every weekday, e.g. Mon-Fri?

Comment: My requirement is to show the employees who are out for each specific day but only show one day at a time.  Example would be to only show the employees who are out for today (Monday).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone does run into this issue and until Microsoft can give us a work around with recurrences I needed to make multiple views that will have to be selected each day.  Very cumbersome but after hours of searching this was the only viable option I could find.

I created two new columns that you can hide if you so choose; "day of the week" and "week #".  I used these two columns to assist me in the filtering of the views. as you can see below.

[image]

With this I had to create two views for the same day of the week.  For the "week #" column I gave each week an identifier:

Week 1 = 1
Week 2 = 2
Every Week = 4

I hope this can help someone else in the future and hopefully there will be an actual fix in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a filter to your view with the following settings:

- `[Start Date of Outage]` `is less than or equal to` `[Today]`

AND

- `[End Date of Outage]` `is greater than or equal to` `[Today]`

This requires that your columns `[Start Date of Outage]` and `[End Date of Outage]` are in a supported `Date`-format.

Comment: This shows all events.

Comment: Because I have been searching this topic for almost two days, would it be more beneficial for me but a little more work in the end to just create a column for the specific days of the week (Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday) and for those days just filter the events by that?  I really don't see any other way around it other preloading all the information in for the year and just filter the information three times a week.

Comment: Unless you maintain your list weekly, it'll start to show the results of the previous weeks too where the employee had an alternate work schedule. Doable, but I still think there's a way to automatize this. To the "This shows all events" -comment: Your example screencap includes a result which indeed falls to these "rules" (= filters). Are there some example inputs which are either in the past or in the future which shouldn't be shown? I hope you understand what I'm after with my result - we want to determine a filter which shows *only lines where today's date is between those two dates*.

Comment: This is what I just added.    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0AUo.jpg

Comment: I just fixed the answer, as I noticed I had by mistake put `less` and `greater` words the opposite they should be. I tried this on my test list and the filter shows only the list items which have their date range including today's date.

Comment: The change does work to show events that were made in the past that should fall on the current day.  But if I had a future event for recurrence, it shows that event as well.